# PowerShell: Delete multiple entrys from a csv file

Tags: csv, powershell, collections

I got a script which works intensely with csv files. In those files different kind of data is stored. At some point I want to delete entrys from such files.

When I want to delete a single entry I do it like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter ";"
$selectedEntry = $csv | Out-GridView -Title $title -OutputMode Single
$csv = $csv -notmatch $selectedEntry
$csv | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

This approach work quite stable but if I change the parameter -OutputMode from Single to Multiple, the following line doesnt work anymore:

```
$csv = $csv -notmatch $selectedEntry
```

Why is this so? How can I delete multiple entrys from a csv file?

Comment: Are `$selectedEntry` and `$item` supposed to be the same variable?

Comment: Sorry, yep, `$item`is suppose to be `$selectedEntry`, I edited it in the question. Thanks for your quick response! The operator NotContains works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with an array differencing `Where-Object` clause.

```
$selectedEntry = $csv | Out-GridView -Title $title -OutputMode Multiple
$filteredCsv = $csv | where { $selectedEntry -notcontains $_ }
```

This iterates over each element of the `$csv` array, and only produces the ones that are not in the `$selectedEntry` array.